# Installing Intel 82579 drivers on Debian 6.01a without any issues, but the NIC disappears after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, debian-squeeze

I'm currently working with Debian 6.01a and the 1.2.20 and 1.3.10a drivers from the Intel site for the 82579 NIC. I modprobe -r e1000e and then insmod /filepath/e1000e.ko. After running ifconfig -a, the 82579 NIC shows up. The problem is after I reboot, the NIC disappears again and I have to go through the modprobe -r/insmod process again. Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: Never mind, found the answer. Ran mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-`uname -r`. Since Debian already had the e1000e drivers as a part of the initrd.img file, it would just load the old drivers instead of loading the drivers that were just installed. Ran the command, and everything's running fine now.

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it so we know that the question is solved.

Comment: Was going to, but it wouldn't let me since I'm new to superuser and the 8 hour mark hadn't passed yet =\

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Ran mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-`uname -r`. Since Debian already had the e1000e drivers as a part of the initrd.img file, it would just load the old drivers instead of loading the drivers that were just installed. Ran the command, and everything's running fine now.